# Can I track multiple events in an anchor in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I track multiple events in an anchor in HTML?

Im already have an onClick event being tracked, but I want to track onRelease as well.

If so whats the best way to do it?

This is a basic example of how I have it implemented:

```
<a href="#" onclick="function();" class="pickbutton hidden-text" id="120btn">120</a>
```

Could this work?

```
<a href="#" onclick="function1();" onRelease="function2();" class="pickbutton hidden-text" id="120btn">120</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach as many events as you like. The preferred way to attach events is to do it in a javascript file, or  tag, rather than as attributes on the element.

```
foo = getElementById('my_element_id');
foo.addEventListener('eventName', functionToExecute);
```

This is much easier with a framework such as query.

```
$('#my_element_id').bind('eventName', functionToExecute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out mouse eventsat [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

- onclick
- ondblclick
- onmouseup
- onmousedown
- onmouseover
- onmouseout
- onmousemove

Comment: So this are the only 3 events that can be tracked simultaneously?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on valid events, I will use onmouseup

Comment: @Aposto: onmouseup occurs right before the click is registered.  A click requires a mousedown and mouseup over the element; whereas a mouseup requires you to click anywhere on the page and release it over that element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can track as many events as you want (although I'm not sure that onRelease is actually an event), but let's [find out](http://jsfiddle.net/YjPc3/1/).